# driven animation in notification bar

Tags: android, android-animation, android-notifications

is it possible to control the animation in the notification bar?

I was able to make a simple flicker using this code:

*drawable xml file: /drawable/tracker_animation.xml*

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/user_location_on" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/user_location_on_blick" android:duration="1000" />
</animation-list>
```

and set it to notification builder:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tracker_animation);
```

but now I want to control the animation. eg run it only when new coordinates. or sending coordinates to the server.

I set

```
android:oneshot="true"
```

and I want to get AnimationDrawable for start animation manually when I want.
for other views it doing like this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);

// Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

// Start the animation (looped playback by default).
frameAnimation.start();
```

but from `NotificationManager` I can't do `.getBackground()`

Answer (score 0):

use of animation for this purposes it was the wrong direction.

better to use is [LevelListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html).
but it has the issue described on the [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43179&q=setSmallIcon&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

In my case I just need to show the interaction with the Internet so I made a very simple, but maybe not very nice:

*before execute request*

```
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.user_location_on_blick);
Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

*after get response callback*

```
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.user_location_on);
Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```